# Show recipient's email address in mailing list

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I am getting spam to one of my e-mail addresses. The recipient's address, however, only shows an mailing list (I guess), to which I have never subscribed:

[image]>

I am trying to find out, to which mail address this mail was sent. I am using a catchall `info@mydomain.com` address, but I never use that to sign up for any website. Instead, I would use `stackoverflow@mydomain.com`. So now, **I am trying to find out, which website gave away my e-mail address for spamming**, but I cannot find a way to see the `<culprit>@mydomain.com` in the recipient.

I am running macOS Sierra.

Comment: It might also be a phoney To: address with a long string of BCC’s— the full headers probably won’t help but you should check them for clues (if it’s a valid mailing list you might get lucky there).  You would need server logs to track it down, and if you have catch-all as you say you’ll likely be chasing your tail.